# jQuery addClass method is using transition

Tags: jquery, css

When I add class in jQuery, the transition from the div I'm adding the class is also used but I don't understand why :

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown').addClass('load');
```

```
.dropdown{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

It takes 0.5sec to add the class and this is a problem.

How can I handle that? I thought about deleting the transition then re-adding but this is not a clear solution.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A CSS transition cannot modify how long it takes to add a class in jQuery. Your problem must be caused by something else.

Comment: The class will be added **instantly**, but if the class 'load' modifies _any_ css property of .dropdown, those property changes are what is taking 0.5 seconds. This is because you're using "transition: **all**". Try and be more _specific_ with your transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why this happens.*

You are saying ALL changes in dropdown should be have a transition.
The changes happening to dropdown are the changes of the extra class.

*How to fix?*

1. If only one transition is needed.

**Example: Only change color**

```css
transition: color 0.5s ease;
```

2. If multiple are needed. Specify your animation onto a lower level.

**Example: Change all with class shoud_be_animated**

```css
.dropdown .should_be_animated {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: it's "ease", not "easy"

Comment: It's also worth noting that the duration property should be second.

Comment: This is the solution I needed, thanks you very much for explanations :)